# Cannot install .apk on Android signed with my own keystore (corona sdk)

Tags: coronasdk, android-keystore

when I'm using android debug key everything works, but today I'm preparing to publish my game and I've created my own keystore using this command:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

I'm using this guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

And when I'm signing app with this keystore I can't install it on my android device.
I'm just getting error that app cannot be installed (yes, I've deleted old app before installation).

Help please!

P.S. I don't know if it's important or not, but I've tried keytool from java 6 and 7 and effect is the same.

Comment: try this command to verify the signature of the apk: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk

Comment: It's working now. THe problem was I had to use the same name and alias name.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code the generate your Keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore mykeystore.keystore -alias aliasname -keyalg RSA -validity 999999
```

If it still doesn't install your device might not be ARAM v7 processor or might not have Android 2.2.  Also there could be an error in your build.settings or config.lua file that is corrupting the install.  Have you tried installing your APK with ADB? Usually ADB will let you know what the error is when installing.  Use `./adb install your.apk` and when you run the game use `./adb logcat` to debug the game.

Comment: logcat says: 12-07 13:01:25.935: E/PackageParser(2259): Package pl.mk.GoldFish has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring! I've got Samsung Galaxy S3 and android 4.1. I tried installing via adb too: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]